# "Unknown datum" opening GRS80 Transverse Mercator in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf, transverse-mercator

I am working with a shapefile (available [here](https://statewidedatabase.org/pub/data/G06/state/srprec_g06_state_shp.zip) as a 15MB ZIP) with a projection defined as follows:

`GEOGCS["GCS_GRS_1980",DATUM["D_GRS_1980",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.2572221]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]`

As far as I can tell this is [GRS 1980 Transverse Mercator](https://www.spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/esri-transverse-mercator-gcs_grs_1980/html/).

I am able to open this shapefile using `st_read("srprec_p04_state_shp")` but the output includes the following:

`Geodetic CRS:  Unknown datum based upon the GRS 1980 ellipsoid`

Is this "unknown datum" a red flag, or is it OK?

I just want to avoid erroneous output in subsequent spatial operations.

**Edit:** I've been informed by the data provider that the correct datum is NAD83, so I'll be setting that manually after reading in the shapefile. I'm still curious, though: What is `"D_GRS_1980"`? My understanding is that GRS80 is just an ellipsoid/spheroid, not a complete CRS, as discussed [here](https://community.esri.com/t5/coordinate-reference-systems/grs-80-to-wgs84/td-p/849211). And I can see that a NAD83 .prj file:

`GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]`

looks quite similar to the one that was packaged with the shapefile I'm working with, aside from the first argument in `DATUM`.

Answer (score 1):

It means that no datum has been specified. So the position of the data on the Earth's surface is not certain. If you are just looking at districts, then it may not be an issue, as they are all ok in relation to another. If you are analysing rasters or other polygon layers in the area based on polygons from this shape, you may have minor issues.

Also, *rename the .dbf file to lower case*. Otherwise, some GIS software won't show you the attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I’m analyzing its relationship to a separate polygon later, so I’d like it to be as clean as possible. One thing I’m confused about though: is D_GRS_1980 in the prj file not a real datum? Is that just some kind of placeholder?

Comment: It can't be projected if there is no datum, so you won't get easting/northing. If you do everything in lat-long, you should be fine. You could assume it's NAD83 and project accordingly, if there weren't several hundred different versions of NAD83. Look in QGIS under the list of CRSes.